# Is there a tool to convert ANSI C code to C#?

Tags: c#, c

I need to import some ANSI C code into a project I'm working on. For reasons I prefer not to go into, I want to refactor the code to C# rather than trying to wrap the original code. It will take me perhaps a couple of days to do the work by hand, but before I start, is there an automated tool that can get me most of the way there? I'm a cheapskate and the work I'm doing is pro bono, so free tools only please.

Comment: Glad to see you admit you're a cheapskate. ;-)

Comment: I'm actually not a cheapskate on my own accord, but I'm giving my time to that particular project for free and so I'm not prepared to spend money on it. When I do paid work, I try to use the best tools I can afford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If manual refactoring is "only" going to take a few days, that would get my vote. Depending on what the C code is doing and how it is written (pointers, custom libraries, etc.) an automated converter may just make a mess. And untangling that mess could be a larger task than just converting by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up, cleaning up, refactoring, and just plain making converted code (if there is even a converter available) would probably be something in the magnitude of weeks or months, so you'll be better served just to go ahead with the manual rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental [CLI Back-End and Front-End](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cli.html) for GCC.  It is already capable of compiling a subset of C programs into CIL, the byte-code that the CLR runs.

(The webpage makes it seem like the code was only developed over a few months and then ignored since then, but it's out of date; [ST Microelectronics](http://www.st.com/) is continuing maintenance and development.)

You don't specify *why* you want a C to C# translator, but if you just want to get C and C# to play together without P/Invoke or COM, it might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

It may make sense to start by getting the existing code to compile as managed C++ aka C++/CLI. Assuming that went smoothly enough, then you have a working, testable foundation on which to build. Move key features to their own classes, and as needed, rewrite as C# along the way.